# Fastest method: Split string and get last element

Tags: python, list, performance, optimization, list-comprehension

I have a list of urls:

```
urls = ['https://www.website.com/407161a', 'https://www.website.com/359426a', 'https://www.website.com/441885a', 'https://www.website.com/331791a']
```

I'm trying to split each url string on `/` and get the last element, for the following output: `['407161a', '359426a', '441885a', '331791a', '403123a']`.

I use this code to get the above: `[u.rpartition('/')[2] for u in urls]`. The problem: it's somewhat slow on larger lists. It takes ~0.75 seconds on a list with 2 million urls on my machine. I'm trying to find a faster method since I'll be running this multiple times on lists containing 10+ million elements.

**Is there a way to make this code faster?**

Comment: Don't think you really can make this any faster, but depending on what you want you might make it more responsive by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension (if you don't need all the elements at once).

Comment: These are a lot of elements regardless of the method. Maybe you can improve efficiency elsewhere. Do you you really need all of those tokens in an in-memory list at once?

Comment: 2.7 million urls per second doesn't sound slow to me...

Comment: good points. I guess I ask bc from my experience there always seems to be some method (perhaps in numpy) that makes things an order of magnitude faster

Comment: At 2 million elements, a total of ~0.75s means about 500ns per element. That's pretty fast, actually. Even something as simple as doubling 2 million numbers is only 4 times faster.

Comment: What are you going to do with the results?

Comment: I doubt numpy would be better. After all, it's numpy. Not strpy.

Comment: Are the elements you search for always 7 characters long as in the example?

Comment: they vary from 2 to 10 characters, but no more than 10

Comment: Okay, then, is it always the same URL _before_ the number? Hm, but `[u[24:] for u in urls]` is still ~ 425 ns vs. 600 for `rpartition`. I think your best deal is trying to make it (a) lazy or (b) parallel. That depends on what you want to do, though.

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah that [would be good](https://tio.run/##fVBdi4MwEHzPr1gKxUQ8bRr7JfhLRA69pm1ATUhW5H69l2jpy911XwKzszOTMd/40IM4GzvPN6t7QNVLhaB6oy2ClUY2SMhoOwclVNED0bgiy6ZpSifZOoUy/dJ9lu9O/MibKIF/KeJwyffHt5Q85@fz4b2K4KeLN6ohBr6L4wMhTncjKj0sCQn42VRjak1jUQWcRlnEqn0NN21hBDVA@E69SZ5clVpnOoWBl3BWffCVqn5Tx2qfF38I1YQE7DNgthnukgpWLDcB9gHD4pVz3YQJbYfYzpctr3Stm3piAvdOt03nyudLWQLD2LfSlpyxl4CxakAa02grrhFsgWLoRQq2GGOwXTyqQtRewSuvt@sdm@cf).

Comment: @tobias_k bingo - that was the small creative tweak that I was looking for. decreases the time to ~0.5s on my machine, which is a solid improvement in percentage terms

Comment: Glad that was of help, but what exactly are you doing with 40 MB of redundant URLs in the first place?

Comment: @tobias_k its a relatively common occurrence when you're parsing large website sitemaps

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.rsplit` with maxsplit parameter as `1` (using `rsplit` with maxsplit parameter will just avoid unnecessary splits), then take the last element. You can use list-comprehension for each of the items.

```py
>>> [i.rsplit('/',1)[-1] for i in urls]
['407161a', '359426a', '441885a', '331791a']
```

Comment: Is this any faster?

Comment: hmm seems like `rsplit` is marginally slower than `rpartition`, at least on my machine. takes 0.8 seconds

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, much faster than `partition` and normal `split`

Comment: Well, I assume it's faster than a lot of unsuitable things. The question is whether it's faster than ``rpartition``.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Please include your benchmark.

Comment: `%timeit` reports ~600ns for `rpartition` vs 750ns for `rsplit`

Comment: [Here's mine](https://tio.run/##fVDRioMwEHzPVyyFYiJWm0ZbK/RLRA57TduAmpCsyH29l2gp93Ldl4XZ2ZnZNT/41IMojZ3nu9U9oOqlQlC90RbBSiNbJGS0nYML1NET0bgqy6ZpSid5dQpl@q37LN@f@JG3UQL/UkRxzg/Hj5Q852VZfFYR/HT2Rg3EwPdxXBDidDei0sOSkICvTT2m1rQWVcBplEWsPjRw1xZGUAOEc5pN8uKq1DrTKQy8hLN6x1eq@kttCAnYV8BsOzwkFaxaBALsI4TBO8k6CRX@GYI5/055o@tDqScm8Oj0te3c5dUpS2AY@6u0F87YW8BYNSCNabQVtwi2QDFcLgVbjDHYLh51JRqv4JXX3XWPzfMv), rpartition is ~20% faster.