# How do I split on the second " , "

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I am trying to split on the second,

```
file = open()
dictionary = {}
for linje in filen:
    bites = linje. split()
    month = bites[0]
    temp = bites[0]
    dictionary[month] = temp
print(dictionary)
```

The file looks like this:

```
Jan,1,2.7
Jan,2,2.8
Jan,3,0.7
Jan,4,1.8
Jan,5,1.2
...... each day every day of the year.
```

If I write `split(",")` the output becomes this in my dictionary:

```
{Jan : Jan}.
```

If I don't split it becomes like this:

```
{Jan,1,2.7 : Jan,1,2.7}
```

I want it to be like this:

```
{Jan,1: 2.7}
```

Comment: `date=','.join([bites[0], bites[1]])`; `temp = bites[2]`; `dictionary[date] = temp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split from the right and specify how many splits to have:

```
with open('file_name') as filen:
    dictionary = {}
    for linje in filen:
        month, value = linje.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)
        dictionary[month] = value
    print(dictionary)
```

Sidenote: I suggest opening files as a context manager, i.e. with `with` statement.

Comment: @victorialangoe rpartition faster than rsplit, see this link with 2 million sentences : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210306/fastest-method-split-string-and-get-last-element/69212023#comment122329914_69212023

Comment: @user1740577 You'll spend more time writing "`rpartition`" than saving on 365 lines

Comment: I have hard time to understand you ;)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Technically, `linje.rpartition(',')` is 21 characters, whereas `linje.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)` is 29 characters ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I would've go with the 'rsplit' solutions above me, but here's a solution with normal split:

```
file = open()
dictionary = {}
for linje in filen:
    digit,temp= linje[4:].split(',')
    month = linje[:4] # Months are represented by 3 chars. (4, including the comma)
    dictionary[month+digit] = temp #concat the digit to the month
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: If you're assuming that columns have fixed width, you shouldn't use split at all: `dictionary = {linje[:5]: linje[6:] for linje in filen}`

Comment: @Stef when you'll get to Oct (10)-Dec(12) you'll need to change the lengths of the slices

Answer (score 2):

Split once with `rsplit`.

```
>>> part1, part2 = 'Jan,3,0.7'.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)
>>> part1
'Jan,3'
>>> part2
'0.7'
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
file = '''Jan,1,2.7
Jan,2,2.8
Jan,3,0.7
Jan,4,1.8
Jan,5,1.2'''
file = file.split('\n')

keys = []
keysdata = []
for i in range(len(file)):
    files = file[i].split(',')
    keys.append(f'{files[0]}, {files[1]}')
    keysdata.append(float(files[2]))
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, keysdata))

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```py
{'Jan, 1': 2.7, 'Jan, 2': 2.8, 'Jan, 3': 0.7, 'Jan, 4': 1.8, 'Jan, 5': 1.2}
```

Comment: I suggest using `keys.append((files[0], int(files[1])))` instead, to store the keys as actual python pairs (month, day).